# Structured Binding not working in VS 2019

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019

Trying to compile below sample C++ code that uses Structured Biding from C++17 standard in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.11.3

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    struct Point
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
    
    // Driver code
    int main()
    {
        Point p = { 1,2 };
    
        // Structure binding
        auto [x_coord, y_coord] = p;
    
        cout << "X Coordinate : " << x_coord << endl;
        cout << "Y Coordinate : " << y_coord << endl;
    
        return 0;
    }
```

And getting below errors. Looks like it's not able to identify the C++ 17 structured binding. I have set the compiler in project properties to be C++17.

```
Error (active)  E0040   expected an identifier      
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "x_coord" is undefined       
Error (active)  E0017   expected a ']'      
Error (active)  E1593   cannot deduce 'auto' type (initializer required)        
Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'          
Error   C2429   language feature 'structured bindings' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17'
```

[image: Project Properties and Compiler setting]

Comment: Is this struct sufficiently tuple-like to work as the right hand side of a structured binding declaration? It looks like there's [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2141r0.html) that suggests aggregates like `Point` _should be_, but I don't think they currently are.

Comment: @NathanPierson this struct is definitely tuple-like enough to work with structured bindings. The error messages seem like there's something wrong with the compiler / setup. It mentions the requirement of C++17 flag, while we can clearly see that OP has it enabled. Something's off with the config or the build.

Comment: This works for me. Are you sure your configuration settings match your build configuration?

Comment: @Fureeish Good point. Checked this myself in godbolt and Visual Studio and it seems to work as OP expected. Evidently the C++17 flag isn't actually being applied when compiling this particular project?

Comment: “Error   C2429   language feature 'structured bindings' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17'” looks much like the flag is missing somehow. Make sure you configure it in the right place (project settings?), and not override it in the wrong place (build configuration?)

Comment: I have attached an image where the C++17 flag was set. Is there another place to do this?

Comment: When you set your compiler standard, you might want to make sure you are setting it for All Configurations and All Platforms. These are on the settings dialog, at the top.

Comment: IDEs are the devil.  The only things worse are makefiles, metabuild systems, and command line manual compiling.

Comment: It works for me on *VS2017* - C++ standard set to "latest".

Comment: Don't forget there is a different group of settings for each platform and configuration.  At the top of that dialog you'll see a couple of dropdown boxes.  It may be that you've tweaked the settings for the non-active configuration, or you've fixed it for e.g. `Debug` but then finding `Release` doesn't build.  There is the `All Configurations` option which is useful for tweaking project-wide settings.